# how i can use like_by_feed of instapy bot?

Tags: instagram, instapy

hello when i use like_by_feed it dosen't working and just return
---->> Total of links feched for analysis: 0
---->> Total of links feched for analysis: 0

i think the problem of the xbath -->> //article/div[2]/div[2]/a this xpath use when the bot want to get linke of post

Answer (score 0):

The xpath seems to be broken. You can use the following to fix the Like By Feed

1. Find the file "xpath_compile.py" (I'm on Windows : \Python\Lib\site-packages\instapy\xpath_compile.py)
2. Find and replace the text

```
xpath["get_links_from_feed"] = {"get_links":
"//article/div[3]/div[2]/a"}
```

with

```
xpath["get_links_from_feed"] = {"get_links":
"//article/div/div[3]/div[2]/a"}
```

3. Save the file and run your Bot again.